# How can I set a value in an object based on if there's an entry in localStorage or not?

Tags: javascript

I have code that sets up my loginData object:

```
user.loginData = {
    userName: "",
    password: "",
    rememberMe: "",
    grant_type: "password",
};
```

Depending on if I have previously stored the userName into localStorage:

```
localStorage.userName = "Joe";
```

How can I make it so the loginData object has a userName of "" if there's nothing stored in localStorage and it use the stored value if there is something stored
in localstorage?

Comment: I am not sure if understand your question?

Comment: I am looking for something on the lines of the answer by at0ma but his solution does not work. Which bit do you not understand. Let me know and I hope I can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
user.loginData = {
    userName: (localStorage.userName&&localStorage.userName.length>0) ? localStorage.userName : "",
    password: "",
    rememberMe: "",
    grant_type: "password",
};
```

localStorage.userName.length>0 ? localStorage.userName : "" translates to

```
if( localStorage.userName.length > 0 )
{
  user.loginData.userName = localStorage.userName;
}
else
{
  user.loginData.userName = "";
}
```

You need to have localStorage defined before filling user.loginData.

Comment: localStorage is defined but I still get this message: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined   I think your answer does not properly take into account that there may not be anything stored for userName. Any ideas on how I could fix this?

Comment: I've updated my sample :
(localStorage.userName && localStorage.userName.length>0) ? localStorage.userName : "",